# Some style of ReactJS not applied in browser

Tags: css, reactjs, html-rendering

I have a ReactJS app that I'm running on a local machine. When I use Mozilla or Chrome to visit the webpage on my main machine, everything works fine, and the styles are properly displayed.

[image: Normal behavier]

However, if I take my laptop, and use both Mozilla or Chrome to view the exact same page, part of the style that's supposed to be loaded is discarded (mostly `flex` stuffs and MaterialUI).

[image: Abnormal behavior]

As you can see, fonts seems to fallback to the default, and flex directives are messed up.

Both computers are running Firefox 66.0.5. Browsing from my smartphone works fine (all the styles are showing). Nothing in the console seems to complain about an XSS blocking or whatever. What's even more strange is that you can see that *some* of the style is showing up (green backgrounds, FontAwesome icons) .. But not all of it ...

I'm really running out of ideas. **Why isn't my style showing on all machines ?**

By the way, the main machine **is not the one that is hosting the React App**, I'm always browsing on a different machine than the one that hosts the app.

Comment: It's because of the resolution difference between the laptop screen and the other systems. and of course bad usage of responsive components.

Comment: No, that's something else. You can clearly see the font is different on both screenshots, and this **cannot** be caused by laptop screen size of _bad usage of responsive components_.

Comment: Go to your browser setting and change the font

Comment: zoom in/out on both system browsers to see, what I mean by bad design

Comment: The browser's font ? Really ? How do you think that works ? Do you have to set a different font on your browser when you use Stack Overflow ? Does Facebook use Times new roman unless you set it to the proper font ? On the second screenshot, the page should use Roboto because **that's what I have set up**.

Comment: Anyway it is one problem, bad design and wrong usage of `Material UI`

Comment: Clearly something funky happening with the font. Have you looked into any child class inheriting this parent class font. I recommend some inspect. FYI in Chrome: DevTools&#39; &quot;Elements&quot;, go to its &quot;Computed&quot; tab, and scroll all the way down to the section called &quot;Rendered Fonts&quot;
 
 Find something similar in Firefox. They too have built in tools to check rendered fonts.

Comment: My "Computed" tab doesn't have any "Rendered fonts", but rather "font-family" which indeed specifies "Roboto" which is the font that is supposed to be rendered.